# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, instance, fabricjs

I'm trying out fabric.js, and right now I'm trying to put in an image to experiment with.

I've followed [the tutorial](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-1/#images) but even so I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of null
```

... which refers to line 14805 in all.js:

```
_setWidthHeight: function(options) {
    this.width = 'width' in options
        ? options.width
        : (this.getElement().width || 0);    // <------ this line
    this.height = 'height' in options
        ? options.height
        : (this.getElement().height || 0);
},
```

**My code (html):**

```
...
<div id="avatarBox">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"/>
    <img src="img/test.png" id="my-image">
</div>
...
```

**My code (js):**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
var imgElement = document.getElementById('my-img');

var imgInstance = new fabric.Image(imgElement, {
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    angle: 30,
    opacity: 0.85
});

canvas.add(imgInstance);
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have "my-img" in your html. You have "my-image", maybe the problem comes from there?

Comment: Great, didn't see that one! Error in their docs then... Thanks!